# How to reliably end a thread blocked on an IO task

Tags: c++

I have a class which executes a thread in order to constantly read lines from a given istream, which are then parsed internally. At some point I want it to end, but since the `getline()` call is blocking, it may wait forever on `join()`.

```
#pragma once

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Parser {
private:
    std::istream& input;
    std::thread parserThread;

public:
    Parser(std::istream& input_) : input(input_)/* ... */{}
    
    ~Parser() {
        stop();
    }
    
    void start() {
        // Avoid multiple threads...
        parserThread = std::thread(&Parser::monitorThread, this);
    }
    
    
    void stop() {
        continueParsing = false;    
        parserThread.join(); // Wait for it to finish
        continueParsing = true; // Allow to start another thread at a later point
    }
    
    
private:
    void monitorThread() {
        std::string buffer;
    
        // Constantly reads new input until it's told to stop
        while(std::getline(input, buffer) && continueParsing) { 
            //...
        }

    }
};
```

Is there any standard way to accomplish this? Or is my approach (have a thread reading forever) wrong? If it were C I would just kill the thread...

Comment: Nothing I know of in Standard C++.  You might like to checkout Boost.Asio .  Killing a thread on most platforms will lead to Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: My immediate thought is why are you pulling the rug out from under the process that is feeding you data? Can there be no cooperation between the two?

Comment: @Galik It's a pretty big Python application which constantly outputs json lines with voice recognition tokens, so I thought of simply piping its output to my C++ program.

Comment: Killing a thread is usually a terrible idea in *any* language; you might not be able to later close a stream, for instance, from which the thread had been reading.

Comment: Maybe use something that processes character by character and appends to `buffer`? If cancelled flag is set, then break out of the loop immediately. Also, your code isn't thread safe.. You need to be using `atomic`, `mutex`, and `condition_variable` to signal the thread that it should stop processing work, then join it after. Another issue is calling `start` twice.. your previous thread's destructor will get called and it will throw an exception since it is not joined or detached.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks! I did not think of that implication...

Comment: @Brandon true, I removed a lot of code for the example. I indeed check if the thread is already started, and the continueParsing is an `std::atomic<bool>`, which I assume is sufficient? (I had never used `std::atomic` before, but otherwise I would have enclosed the boolean check between mutexes) Also, the monitorThread uses C++20's semaphores to signal that new data is available and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `std::getline` encounters end-of-file, then it will immediately return and stop blocking. Therefore, if you could somehow arrange for this to happen when you want the thread to exit, then that would probably be the best solution. However, if that is not possible, then I'm afraid that ISO C++ itself does not offer any way to solve the problem.

But most platforms offer platform-specific extensions which allow you to wait on more than one kernel object at once. For example, Linux offers [`poll`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and [`epoll`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) which allows you to wait for input on a file descriptor and to wait for an event object in the same function call (actually, Linux considers event objects also to be file descriptors). Microsoft Windows offers similar functionality with [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects).

You could create an event object (using [`eventfd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) on Linux, [`CreateEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventa) on Windows) and set this event object to signalled when you want your thread to cancel the wait and to quit. If the thread is waiting for either the event object to become signalled or for new input on the file descriptor, then it will stop waiting as soon as the event becomes signalled. That way, you will no longer have the problem of the thread blocking while waiting for new input on the file descriptor.

If you want to implement this solution and continue using `std::istream` for input, then you may want to consider deriving your own [`std::streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) class which implements the member function [`underflow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/underflow) in such a way that it first calls one of the platform-specific functions `poll`/`epoll`/`WaitForMultipleObjects` to wait for either new input to become available or for the quit event to become signalled. If the quit event is signalled, then the function `underflow` should return `Traits::eof()`, which will cause the [`eofbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) in `std::istream` to be set and `std::getline` to return immediately. Otherwise, as soon as new input is reported to be available, you can call one of the platform-specific functions [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)/[`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) to fill the get area of the `std::streambuf` object, adjusting the pointers of the object as necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just to add for future reference, I also found a really uglier solution by making a non-blocking `std::getline` with static buffers and `readsome`. I will check this too, this sounds like a perfect summer excercise!